# Will one’s education loan application be rejected if one doesn't have a payslip providing collateral?

Tags: india, loans, bank-account, student-loan, education-savings

Is it possible to reject education loan by SBI/IOB for abroad if don’t have payslip where parents are doing small business but provided necessary collateral which is worth twice the value approved by valuer of the bank. Is it possible to reject loan stating this?

Comment: Could you explain a little bit more. I have problem understanding your point: You want to refuse the loan, your parents make enough money to help you so you do not need the loan. I am confused. Please explain Balaji.

Comment: @Armando The OP is not a native speaker of English, and what he meant to ask is whether it is possible that a bank (SBI = State Bank of India) will reject a loan application for study abroad if the parents (who have a small business and are guaranteeing the loan) cannot provide a proof of a regular income in the form of a pay slip from an employer.

Answer (score 2):

A bank can reject a loan if they feel you do not meet the eligibility criteria.

You can talk to few banks and find out.